# IntelliJ IDEIA and CLion has difference between UI's fonts

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, fonts, ubuntu-16.04, clion

I'm using all in same settings and a I've this difference in quality of the fonts, what is this?

[image: Diference between fonts]

waiting for answers,

SO: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Arc-theme, but the the system fonts are the default of the system.

Thanks.

Comment: CLion 2016.3.1 as I see, and what is IntelliJ IDEA version?

Comment: The IntelliJ IDEIA version is the same CLion 2016.3.1 =(

Comment: Also, both of them settings are equals

Answer (score 0):

Try Settings / Appearance & Behavior / Appearance / Antialiasing. You probably need to select "Subpixel" or "Greyscale" there.

Comment: I'm tried use all settings Antialiasing, but no success! =(

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you're using the same JRE (Help->About)?

Comment: It's the problem. The CLion use a JRE by JetBrains and IntelliJ use a default system JRE, in this case, I use java-oracle and JetBrains use OpenJDK. I downloaded OpenJDK but and change java boot in IntelliJ IDEA, but no difference.